# Installled openSuse and now can't boot from USB or DVD

Tags: boot, opensuse, dvd, mageia

I've just installed openSuse 13.1 and, while it's great, now I want to try Mageia 4. Problem is that after installing openSuse my machine (Lenovo G560) won't boot from a USB stick or from the DVD drive.

I copied an ISO of Mageia to a USB stick. I then set the boot order in the bios to boot from the USB stick first but rebooting just skips the USB and and boots from the HD. Same thing happens with a DVD image of the Mageia.

Comment: Are the good burns? Have you checked the md5sum\sha512sum? Can you boot off of them in an emulator like VirtalBox or qemu?

Comment: I never got to the bottom of this. In the end I found I could boot to Linux Mint.